# Wireless networks not working

Tags: wireless, networking

I am running Ubuntu 12.10 alongside Windows 7 I can connect to the internet using ethernet but cannot detect any wireless networks. When I use Windows 7 I can connect fine. Any help would be greatly appreciated. The output for lspci -v | grep -iA 10 network was:

```
02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (rev 01)
Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1704 802.11n + BT 4.0
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 11
Memory at c0500000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
```

lsmod:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
joydev                 17457  0 
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     32007  1 
snd_hda_codec_conexant    57842  1 
rfcomm                 46619  12 
bnep                   18140  2 
parport_pc             32688  0 
ppdev                  17073  0 
lp                     17759  0 
parport                46345  3 parport_pc,ppdev,lp
coretemp               13400  0 
kvm_intel             132759  0 
kvm                   414070  1 kvm_intel
ghash_clmulni_intel    13180  0 
cryptd                 20403  1 ghash_clmulni_intel
dell_wmi               12681  0 
sparse_keymap          13890  1 dell_wmi
psmouse                95552  0 
dell_laptop            17369  0 
dcdbas                 14438  1 dell_laptop
microcode              22803  0 
snd_hda_intel          33491  3 
snd_hda_codec         134212  3        snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_conexant,snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep              13602  1 snd_hda_codec
uvcvideo               76749  0 
videobuf2_core         32851  1 uvcvideo
videodev              120309  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_core
videobuf2_vmalloc      12860  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       13368  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
snd_pcm                96580  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec
snd_seq_midi           13324  0 
snd_rawmidi            30512  1 snd_seq_midi
wmi                    19070  1 dell_wmi
btusb                  18334  0 
bluetooth             209199  22 rfcomm,bnep,btusb
snd_seq_midi_event     14899  1 snd_seq_midi
mac_hid                13205  0 
snd_seq                61521  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
snd_timer              29425  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd_seq_device         14497  3 snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq
rts5139               356158  0 
snd                    78734  16   snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_conexant,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hwdep,snd_pcm,s    nd_rawmidi,snd_seq,snd_timer,snd_seq_device
i915                  520519  3 
drm_kms_helper         46784  1 i915
drm                   275528  4 i915,drm_kms_helper
i2c_algo_bit           13413  1 i915
soundcore              15047  1 snd
snd_page_alloc         18484  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm
serio_raw              13215  0 
lpc_ich                17061  0 
mei                    40690  0 
video                  19335  1 i915
r8169                  61650  0
```

iwconfig:

```
eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

rfkill list all

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: press Ctrl-Alt-t. In the terminal run: first `sudo service network-manager restart`, then `lspci -v | grep -iA 10 network`, then `lsmod`, `iwconfig` and `rfkill list all`. Edit your question and post the output of these commands. We need more info to help you.

Comment: Your driver is not installed. Let's see if the easy way works. in the dash search for software sources, open it, go to "additional drivers" tab and look for suggestions. If there is a suggested broadcom driver, activate it. reboot and report back.

Comment: Nothing in additional drivers just says "No proprietary drivers in use".

Comment: please run the first step in my answer and check if the number matches.

Comment: http://jas.gemnetworks.com/wireless-bcm43142/ dkms enabled bcm43142 driver link in the top voted answer is invalid now can anybody provide an alternate link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*If there are no suggested drivers in the Additional drivers tab:*

Before you do this run:

```
lspci -nn | grep -i network
```

and make sure the device number matches this `Broadcom Corporation Device [14e4:4365]`

If that's the case

Download [this dkms enabled bcm43142 driver](http://jas.gemnetworks.com/debian/pool/main/w/wireless-bcm43142/wireless-bcm43142-dkms_6.20.55.19-1_amd64.deb) from jas.gemnetworks.com and save it in your `Download` folder.

In the term run:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential dkms
```

then install the package, still in the term:

```
cd ~/Download
sudo dpkg -i wire*.deb
sudo modprobe wl
```

Comment: When I run sudo dpkg -i wire*.deb the output is:
 'Selecting previously unselected package wireless-bcm43142-dkms.
dpkg: regarding wireless-bcm43142-dkms_6.20.55.19-1_amd64.deb containing wireless-bcm43142-dkms:
 wireless-bcm43142-dkms conflicts with bcmwl-kernel-source
  bcmwl-kernel-source (version 5.100.82.112+bdcom-0ubuntu3) is present and installed.

dpkg: error processing wireless-bcm43142-dkms_6.20.55.19-1_amd64.deb (--install):
 conflicting packages - not installing wireless-bcm43142-dkms
Errors were encountered while processing:
 wireless-bcm43142-dkms_6.20.55.19-1_amd64.deb'

Comment: Please do: sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source and then try again.